# Find a pattern on filenames - Python

Tags: python, pattern-matching

I need to search all .xlsx files that have the following name: mg_YYYMMDD.xlsx
The YYYYMMDD date must be greater than a fixed date that is already set to last_date.

```
last_date = (file.date.max())

filenames = [
    fn for fn in os.listdir()
    if fn.endswith(".xlsx")
      and .....
]
filenames
```

I don't know the last part of the for loop..

Here are examples of the files in the folder:

['mg_20200120.xlsx',
 'mg_20200122.xlsx']

The output of the last_date is: Timestamp('2020-01-21 00:00:00')

Thank you very much!

Comment: Does greater mean more recently or older than the specified date?

Comment: Hi George, greater means more recently. Ty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way would be to use the string itself as a comparison:

```
lastdate = "20200122" #in the form YYYYMMDD

filenames = [fn for fn in os.listdir() if fn.endswith(".xlsx") and fn[0:3] == "mg_" and fn[3:-5] >= lastdate]
```

EDIT: To consider conversion from datetime
if last_date is from python datetime

```
last_date = datetime.now()
f = str(last_date)
new_last_date = f[0:4]+f[5:7]+f[8:10] #YYYY MM DD
```

Comment: That's the most efficient way, best tailored for the specific problem. But you still need to convert `last_date` to the correct string format.

Comment: Thank you Jason, it gives the following erro: TypeError: '<=' not supported between instances of 'numpy.ndarray' and 'str'. Should I turn the dates into another format? I had made an initial parse_dates when importing the file but I took it because I thought it should be treated as a string.

Comment: Right, didn't know it was in a numpy array. I would think if you can get the datetime into a string. Slicing it to do the comparison should be no biggie. Are you using numpy's datetime? Also my code doesnt have "<=" soooo...might be an error elsewhere too.

Comment: Jason Chia thank you very much, it works! I used datetime.now() for last_date but how can i use it with a date of a filename? What's the format? Can be an numpy int?

Comment: Well I do not know where and how you are defining last_date. If its from datetime, you can do what I did. If its a user input, simply put in the same string format as the expected file names. "YYYYMMDD". If it is from some other timestamp format, convert the date to the required string and you are good to go.

Comment: just changed a little the code for: new_last_date = f[0:4]+f[4:6]+f[6:8]

Answer (score 0):

Given the format of your date, I would just treat it like an integer, it should work well.

Try to make a standard loop first. Then you can encapsulate it into a function, then you can use the function a list comprehension. It would be way more readable in this way.

The loop should be something like this:

```
ref_date = int('20200121')
for fn in os.listdir():
    current_file_date = int(fn.split('.')[0].split('_')[-1])
    if current_file_date > ref_date:
        ...
```

Technically, you could compare strings directly, without converting them into integers.

Answer (score 0):

We can use the `datetime` module and its method `strptime`to convert a string into a date, and then to compare the date from the filename with `last_date`:

```
from datetime import datetime

critical_date = datetime.fromtimestamp(last_date)

filenames = [
    fn for fn in os.listdir()
    if fn.endswith(".xlsx")
    and fn.startswith("mg_")
    and datetime.strptime("%Y%m%d", fn[3:-5]) < critical_date
]
```

(This is assuming that the filenames all follow the format `"...YYYYMMDD....."`)
Have a look at the docs:

- https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior
- https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.fromtimestamp

Comment: Thank you jonathan.scholbach, it returns the following error: ValueError: time data '%Y%m%d' does not match format 'iados'